Once the magnetic field lines starting from the north pole of the first magnet reach the south pole of the second magnet how do they loop back?
Gauss' law of magnetism insinuates the looped nature of magnetic field lines, the fact that they never terminate or begin like in a source-sink system. But I am having a hard time to reconcile this fact with the magnetic field interaction of two magnets, say with their opposite poles lined close together, and any image has so far not provided me with an apt visualization, it seems as if the magnetic field lines begin from the north pole of magnet 1 and terminate at the south pole of magnet 2.

You need to continue the field lines within the magnets. The idea is that the field lines entering from one pole will exit by the opposite pole, piercing through the magnet. You can even work things out analytically for uniformly magnetised balls. For one magnet, you would get the following field lines:

For two magnets, the total field gives this:

For arbitrarily shaped magnets, the details of the fields will change, but the global topology will not. As expected, there is no sources and the lines do loop around with no beginning or end.

It should be made clear that you're talking about B, not H. Inside the spherical magnet, H would be half the magnitude of B, and in the opposite direction. For a bar magnet, the lines of B are not straight lines, but still resolve the problem.


Gauss' law of magnetism insinuates the looped nature of magnetic field lines

This is incorrect, although you may find such a claim in many text books. Magnetic lines of force do not necessarily form closed loops, even if they do not go off to infinity.
I will quote from the abstract of Topology of Magnetic Field Lines

Textbooks often hold erroneously that the condition $\nabla\cdot\vec{H}=0$ implies that lines and tubes of force are closed. Examples are given in which the lines of force are not only unclosed, but also, the density of lines may be made infinite in a region where the field intensity is finite.

The paper The Misconception of Closed Magnetic Flux Lines gives a partial illustration of two such magnetic field lines:

The paper Ubiquity of chaotic magnetic-field lines generated by three-dimensionally crossed wires in modern electric circuits shows the field lines created by two current carrying conductive loops on different planes:

And also the magnetic field generated in a simple electronic circuit:


The above misconception aside, in the case of two permanent magnets, as in the original post, the magnetic field lines continue through the permanent magnets. They do not begin and end at the surface of the magnetic poles. This is explained in another answer, so I don't feel the need to explain this further.

Perhaps the down-voter would care to argue their point?
